# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Mac: Where is server explorer?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I’m trying to make an SQL connection using server explorer, but I can’t seem to locate it on Visual Studio 2017 on Mac. I tried creating a New Solution as well and look for it under View, but it still does not pop up.

Where could it be located?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to accept/upvote answer!

Comment: "Server Explorer" is a feature of the "real" Visual Studio - for Windows. "Visual Studio for Mac" is a rebrand of Xamarin Studio and it does not have feature parity with Visual Studio for Windows. Similarly you won't find the WinForms and WPF editors, Compact Framework, DirectX tools and Windows SDK integration, etc.

Comment: @Dai Is there any way to add the "Server Explorer" feature to the VS for Mac? Or any other good alternatives? Thank you!

Comment: You could always run Visual Studio for Windows under Parallels Fusion or some other desktop virtualization system.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Server Explorer is not (yet) available for the Visual Studio for the Mac. Microsoft has not yet clarified whether Visual Studio for the Mac will always be different than the traditional VS, but so far that is the case.

Until Microsoft clarifies, we have to think of Visual Studio for the Mac as "partially compatible" with Visual Studio. Though not quite the same, it's similar to how Visual Studio Code is kept separate, though it keeps the valuable "Visual Studio" name.

Comment: Appreciate the response! Any other alternatives to Server Explorer for VS on Mac?

Comment: The command line: `brew install mssql-tools` then `mssql -s [server ie:127.0.0.1] -o [port ie:1433] -u sa -p [pass] -d [database ie:master]`